# dictionary of dictionaries special case

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a case where, till now i implemented dictionary successfully when the input file is like this:

```
line1 field1   field2   field3   field4   field5  
line2 field1   field2   field3   field4   field5
```

and so on.....

I made line number as the key and the `tuple (field1, field2, field3, field4)` as the corresponding value of my dictionary. Now, i want to include field5 as the value to the `key (field1, field2, field3, field4)`. That means, the `tuple (field1, field2, field3, field4)` need to be key and value at the same time. Is this sort of implementation possible in python?

Comment: I'm confused. Do you mean you want to group rows on `field5` and have a dictionary of dictionaries (as in your title), or are the lines of the file already unique and you just want `field5` to be the key instead of the line number (as in "include...as the value to the key")?

Comment: Tuples can be keys, but do you need the other fields as part of the key?  If field5 is unique, can you use that as the key?  (If you were using line numbers as keys, then wouldn't a list have been simpler?)

Comment: i am making the tuple(field1, field2, field3, field4) as the value and the line number as the key. Basically what i am doing is, if the line1 and line2 keys has the same values, i am deleting both the entries from dictionary. As the new implementation, before deleting the entries, i want to take the difference of field5 values which are timestamps.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question right, Yes. But your going to be wasting an awful lot of space for a large set.

```
dic     = {}
tuple1  = ("field1","field2","field3","field4")

dic["line1"] = tuple1
dic[tuple1]  = "field5"

print dic["line1"]
print dic[tuple1]
```

Comment: I think two dimensional dictionary is required here.

Comment: No, it does not do that.  It creates 2 key-value pairs.  The first being {"line1":tuple1}  The second being {tuple1:"Field5"}.  The end result being that the dictionary has 2 keys each of which index there respective values.

Comment: @rock luke I am still at a lose for why? But never the less, is your question asking how to implement a dictionary of dictionarys?

Answer (score 0):

> That means, the tuple (field1, field2, field3, field4) need to be key and value at the same time. Is this sort of implementation possible in python?

Yes. There is nothing stopping you from doing like this:

```
key = ("f1", "f2", "f3", "f4", "f5")
value = ("f1", "f2", "f3", "f4", "f5")
d = {key: value}
```

If I understand you correctly, you've been doing something like this till now:

```
line_no = 1
d = {}
for line in open(FILE):
    d[line_no] = line  # line = ("f1", "f2", "f3", "f4")
    line_no += 1
```

..?

If not, please elaborate on where I'm wrong or post your source code :)

EDIT:

Okay, thanks for the comment, I think I understand now. I'd do it like this:

```
d = {}
for line in open(FILE):
    d[line] = []
    d[line].append(f5)  # line = ("f1", "f2", "f3", "f4"), f5 = timestamp
```

That way you would use the whole tuple as key and can subtract the timestamps (f5) from records with identical f1,f2,f3,f4. To me that seems much easier to do in SQL though.

That way you would have constant lookup time and linear time as the load increases. But I think you'll suffer a bit of a performance hit if the key is of non-trivial size.

Let me think about how you'd suctract the timestamps from each other..

EDIT2:

Yes, you can make a list of the first element in the pair: fl = [p[0] for p in pairs]] and then filter out anyone with more than 1 occurance:

something like this l2 = [l for l in fl if len(l) > 1]

but that doesn't seem very efficient..

Comment: There is a slight correction to your post. Till now, i am doing d = {LINENO: ("f1", "f2", "f3", "f4")}. Now, i want to associate f5, so that when two lines have same ("f1", "f2", "f3", "f4"), i want to take the difference of f5 of those two lines.

Comment: @jensen Thanks, but i want only the line number as the key and the tuple ("f1", "f2", "f3", "f4") as the value. I based my entire 300 lines of code this way. I don't want to change that. I want the extension of that implementation, thats all.

Comment: So how about you just change the value to pairs of ((f1, f2, f3, f4), timestamp) ?

Comment: @jensen...thats a good idea. But can i still check for the condition if two lines(i.e.two keys) have the same (f1, f2, f3, f4)? If we can do that, can we take the time difference of the two timestamp values?

Answer (score 0):

> http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html?highlight=tuple#tuple
>
> tuple is an immutable sequence type, as documented in Sequence Types —
> str, unicode, list, tuple, bytearray, buffer, xrange. For other
> containers see the built in dict, list, and set classes, and the
> collections module.

Tuples are immutables which means you cannot append or delete item from a tuple. You have to reconstruct the variable to change it. If you plan to change your iterable variable in time, use `list`.

Apart from tuples being immutable, the question is a bit vague.

Here is a way to append `field5` to a dictionary.

```
a = {1:(f1,f2,f3,f4), 2:(f1,f2,f3,f4)} # this is our dictionary contains tuple

for key, value in a.iteritems(): # iterate over dictionary
    a[key] += (field5,) # comma is important, you can only concanate tuple with tuple.


# or you can do
a[linenumber] += (field5,)
```